# First derivative of Lagrange polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

Given the Lagrange basis polynomial as:

$L_i(x)= \prod_{m=0, m \neq i}^n \frac{x-x_m}{x_i-x_m} $

is there a generic equation for the first derivative ${L_i}'(x)$ for any order,t hat is for any $n$?

Comment: We have $$L_i(x)'=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \prod_{l=0, l \neq k}^n (x-x_l)}{\prod_{k=0, k \neq j}^n (x_j-x_k)}$$

Comment: Hi Krokop, I'm a bit confused by your answer with regards to the symbols. What is your $j$? Shouldn't that be $i$?

Comment: Yes your are right. (typo)

Comment: Me again Krokop. Is there a generic formula for any derivative of the Lagrange polynomial? Not just the first.

Answer (score 9):

By the "logarithmic derivative" method, $$\frac{L'_i(x)}{L_i(x)}=\sum_{m=0,\ m\neq i}^n\frac1{x-x_m}.$$

Comment: I know, this question and answer is already a year old, but I'm having some problems understanding the formula. By construction $L_i(x_i)=1$ is ans extrema of the $i-$th basis function (isn't it?). But then, $L_i'(x_i)$ should be zero. But that isn't the case when I'm using the above formula. I understand the derivation but still can't solve this contradiction. Could you help?

Comment: "By construction $L_i (x_i )=1$  is an extremum of the $i^{th}$ basis function": not at all.

Comment: Well then this has to be due to the specific choice of my basis points, I'll take a look into that. Thank you!

Comment: Could you maybe take a look at [the question I formulated](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105160/evaluate-derivative-of-lagrange-polynomials-at-construction-points)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

$$L_{j}(x) = \prod_{i\neq j} \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}} $$

then $$ ln\Big(L_{j}(x)\Big) = ln\Big(\prod_{i\neq j} \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}}  \Big) = \sum_{i \neq j } ln\Big( \frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}} \Big) $$

if we derivate we have:

$$ \frac{L'_{j}(x)}{L_{j}(x)} =\sum_{i \neq j} \frac{\frac{1}{x_{j}-x_{i}}}{\frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{j}-x_{i}}} = \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  $$ 
then

$$ L'_{j}(x) = L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)  $$

if we use the product rule for  derivatives we have that:

$$ L''_{j}(x) = L'_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)+L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)' \\ = 
 L'_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)+L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{-1}{(x-x_{i})^2}  \Big) $$ we know $ L'_{j}(x)  $  so $$ \\ = 
 L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)\Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)-L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^2}  \Big)\\ = 
L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)^2 -L_{j}(x) \Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^2}  \Big) \\ = 
L_{j}(x) \Big\{\Big( \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{x-x_{i}}  \Big)^2 -  \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{(x-x_{i})^2}     \Big\} $$

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest an alternative approach. You can find coefficients of Lagrange interpolation polynomial or any of its derivatives relatively easy if you use a matrix form of Lagrange interpolation presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation". General formula for the polynomial looks as follows
$$
f(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & f_0       & f_1       & \cdots & f_n       \\
        x^n     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        x       & x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Here $(x_0;f_0)$, $\dots$, $(x_n;f_n)$ are the points it passes through. Using Laplace expansion along the first column you can get expressions for coefficients at $x^i$. 
If instead we perform Laplace expansion along the first row, we will get sum containing $f_i\,L_i(x)$, where $L_i(x)$ is a basis polynomial.

If we take derivative of the expression above, it will only act on the first column of the matrix in the numerator (the only one containing $x$'s). One can prove this by expanding determinant in the numerator along the first column, taking derivative and then collecting everything back. As a result, first derivative looks as follows
$$
f'(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0             & f_0       & f_1       & \cdots & f_n       \\
        n x^{n-1}     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        (n-1) x^{n-2} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots        & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1             & x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        0             & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Higher-order derivatives can be calculated the same way --- you change the first column appropriately, all the rest remains.

If you would like to have the derivative of the basis polynomial only, you can do it either way: consider appropriate cofactor only (remove the first row and the column that corresponds to index $i$ you are interested in), or put some formal orthonormal vectors as the first row and find $L_i'$ as appropriate factor at $\vec{e}_i$. The second approach will give you
$$
L'_0(x) \vec{e}_0 + L'_1(x) \vec{e}_1 + \dots + L'_n(x) \vec{e}_n = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0             & \vec{e}_0 & \vec{e}_1 & \cdots & \vec{e}_n \\
        n x^{n-1}     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        (n-1) x^{n-2} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots        & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1             & x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        0             & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$