# Evaluate derivative of Lagrange polynomials at construction points

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, numerical-methods, matlab, interpolation

Assume, that we have points $x_i$ with $i=1,...,N+1$. We construct the Lagrange basis polynomials as
\begin{align}
L_j(x) = \prod_{k\not = j} \frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}
\end{align}

Now according to my computation and the results by Yves Daoust [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809927/first-derivative-of-lagrange-polynomial), the derivative of $L_i$ can be computed as
\begin{align}
L'_j(x) = L_j(x)\cdot \sum_{k\not = j}\frac{1}{x_k-x_j}
\end{align}

I try to reproduce the numerical results of a paper, and for this results the authors use the derivative matrix $D$ with $D_{ij} =L_i'(x_j)$.

The authors use the Legendre Gauss Lobatto quadrature points, plotted below.
[image]
Now I can easily construct the basis polynomials, also plotted below, together with the quadrature points.
[image]

Given the concrete choice of basis points, the plots suggest, that $L'_j(x_j)=0$ except for the first and last basis function. Additionally it seems, that $L'_j(x_i)\not =0$ for $i\not = j$. But using the derived formula from above, we obtain
\begin{align}
L'_j(x_i) = L_j(x_i)\cdot \sum_{k\not = j}\frac{1}{x_k-x_j}=0
\end{align}
for $i\not = j$ since $L_j(x_i) =\delta_{ij}$, which contradicts my observation.

I used the following Matlab functions, to construct the matrix $D$.

```
function y=dl(i,x,z)
n = length(x);
y = 0;
for m=1:n
    if not(m==i)
        y = y + 1/(x(m)-x(i));
    end
end
size(y)
y = y*l(i,x,z);

end



function y=l(i,x,z)

n = length(x);
% computes h_i(z)

y = 1;
for m=1:n
    if not(m==i)
        y = y.*(z-x(m))./(x(i)-x(m));
    end
end
end
```

Where `dl`and `l`are $L'$ and $L$. $D$ is then constructed by

```
D = zeros(M+1,M+1);
for i=1:M+1
    for j=1:M+1
        D(i,j) =dl(i,X,X(j));
    end
end
```

which gives the matrix

```
D =

   10.5000         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0   -0.0000         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0    0.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0   -0.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0    0.0000         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0    0.0000         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0  -10.5000
```

Here I agree with the zeros on the diagonal except for the first and last element. The zeros everywhere else agree with the formula, but they don't agree with my observation.

If I use finite differences (which is no solution for the real implementation) in the following way:        `FD(i,j) =(l(i,X,X(j)+eps)-l(i,X,X(j)-eps))/(2*eps);`
I obtain the output

```
FD =

  -10.5000   -2.4429    0.6253   -0.3125    0.2261   -0.2266    0.5000
   14.2016    0.0000   -2.2158    0.9075   -0.6164    0.6022   -1.3174
   -5.6690    3.4558    0.0000   -2.0070    1.0664   -0.9613    2.0500
    3.2000   -1.5986    2.2667         0   -2.2667    1.5986   -3.2000
   -2.0500    0.9613   -1.0664    2.0070   -0.0000   -3.4558    5.6690
    1.3174   -0.6022    0.6164   -0.9075    2.2158   -0.0000  -14.2016
   -0.5000    0.2266   -0.2261    0.3125   -0.6253    2.4429   10.5000
```

which is zero on the diagonal (except first and last) and nonzero everywhere else.

**So here are my questions:**

Did I make an error in the implementation?

Is my formula derived under the assumption that $x$ is not a basis point?

Can I modify my code to obtain the results that my finite difference code produces?

Is my assumption correct, that rather the results of the finite difference computation are "correct"?

**EDIT**

It seems, like the derivation of the formula goes wrong for $x=x_i$. If I compute the derivative without simplification, I get
\begin{align}
L_j'(x) = \sum_{l\not = j} \frac{1}{x_j-x_l}\prod_{m\not = (j,l)} \frac{x-x_m}{x_j-x_m}
\end{align}
Or in code

```
function y = alternative_dl(j,x,z)

y = 0;
n = length(x);
for l=1:n
    if not(l==j)
        k = 1/(x(j)-x(l));
        for m=1:n
            if not(m==j) && not(m==l)
                k = k*(z-x(m))/(x(j)-x(m));
            end
        end
        y = y + k;
    end
end

end
```

Which agrees with the finite difference computation.

So it seems to me, that simplifying the above formula includes some "hidden division by zero" if $x=x_i$.

Comment: I found your post and the last expression for derivative really useful. Can you look at this post and help me out? I need to find second order derivative and have no idea how. Thanks in advance!
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572576/largange-polynomial-second-order-derivative

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your implementation is correct. You copied the wrong formula.

$$L'_i(x)=L_i(x) \sum_{m=0,\ m\neq i}^n\frac1{x-x_m}$$

This formula would not give you zeros everywhere else.

And this is the same as your new derived formula.

Comment: But your formula contains $L_i(x)$ on the right hand side. Now if I evaluate $L'_i(x_j)$ I get $L_i'(x_j) = L_i(x_j)\cdot \sum...=0\cdot \sum$ since $L_i(x_j)=0$ if $i\not = j$.

Comment: Okay I see, that I copied the formula wrong, but the problem I have in the comment above still exists?!

Comment: When you plug $x_j$ into it, there is also a $x_j-x_j$ in the denominator on the right hand side. I guess that's what you called "hidden division by zero"? In fact, you can expand this formula to get the other formula in the post you referred to: $L_i(x)'=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \prod_{l=0, l \neq k}^n (x-x_l)}{\prod_{k=0, k \neq j}^n (x_j-x_k)}$, which does not contain zero in the denominator.

Comment: Here is a simple 3 point formula. $L_1'(x)=\frac{(x-x_0)+(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)} = \frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}(\frac{1}{x-x_0}+\frac{1}{x-x_2})$. If you evaluate it at $x_2$, you will see you cannot just say it is zero using the second formula.

Comment: Okay, but then I can't use the formula in my implementation, since I end up computing $0/0$ since $(x-x_2)=0$ if $x=x_2$ and $1/(x-x2)=1/0$ if $x=x_2$?

Comment: Use the formula I gave you above in my first comment. That is like the first formula in the 3 point example. No 0/0 will appear.

Comment: Just want to correct the formula given by @KittyL in the comments,
it should be $L_j'(x)=\frac{\sum_{k=0,k\neq j}^n\prod_{l=0,l\neq k,l\neq j}^n(x-x_l)}{\prod_{k=0,k\neq j}^n(x_j-x_k)}$

Answer (score 9):

Just to complement the answer, here is the formula for second derivative:
$$
L^{"}_i(x) =\sum_{l\ne i}\frac{1}{x_i-x_l}\left( \sum_{m\ne(i,l)}\frac{1}{x_i-x_m}\prod_{k\ne(i,l,m)}\frac{x-x_k}{x_i-x_k}\right) 
$$
through recursion, one can compute further higher derivatives.